# Matlab gui: callback containing imrect gets stuck if clicking multiple times

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am writing a GUI in Matlab where a user can process images. Once an image is opened, the user can specify a ROI by a "Crop" button (callback code below). After cropping, further analysis can be done.

Everything works fine except when the user accidentally clicks on the "crop button" without selecting a rectangle. Then, clicking again on the button, I can draw the rectangle but not confirm my selection anymore. I think the "previous" callback is still stuck at the `wait(h)` function which should enable the user to redefine the rectangle (according to http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/imrect.html)

I also tried to include a restart button and to reopen the GUI, but then it is still not possible to select a ROI in the image.

```
% --- Executes on button press in cropButton.
function cropButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Read image
I = handles.I;
hold(handles.axes1,'on');

% Let user choose rectangle to crop
h = imrect(handles.axes1);
position = round(wait(h));
% Crop image
I = imcrop(I,position);

hold(handles.axes1,'off');

% Show cropped image
imshow(I, 'Parent', handles.axes1);

handles.I = I;
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in resetButton.
function resetButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
clear all;
close all;
clc;
MyGUI; % restart GUI
```

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button on click and re-enable it at the end of the callback:

```
% --- Executes on button press in cropButton.
function cropButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.cropButton,'enable','off');

% Read image
I = handles.I;
hold(handles.axes1,'on');

% Let user choose rectangle to crop
h = imrect(handles.axes1);
position = round(wait(h));
% Crop image
I = imcrop(I,position);

hold(handles.axes1,'off');

% Show cropped image
imshow(I, 'Parent', handles.axes1);

handles.I = I;
guidata(hObject, handles);
set(handles.cropButton,'enable','on');
```

Much less complicated.

Comment: I like this approach. I have lots of buttons (others also use the `imrect` function). Is there a possibility to disable all buttons at once?
Another question: Is it possible to "unselect" the crop button if the user decides not crop (like terminating the callback?)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As far as I'm aware there's no built in 'disable all buttons' function. You can disable them with a looped `set` call, either as a separate wrapper function or in the main body of your code. It could get pretty tedious to build up the array of object handles to pass depending on how many buttons you have, but I'm sure there are clever ways to work it to cut down on the work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a "reset" button, you could use findobj to look for a rectangle (i.e. a hggroup object). If no rectangle is found (i.e. you have pressed the crop button without selecting a rectangle), call 'return' and do it again.

Eg:

```
hFindROi = findobj(gca,'Type','hggroup');

if isempty(hFindRoi) % i.e. no rectangle found

msgbox('Please select a rectangle before pressing the Crop button');
return
end
```

Another option would be to use some kind of flags to know whether some callback has been executed. You can store those flags in the handles structure of the GUI so that they are accessible from any callback.

For example, let's say you declare

```
handles.SelectRectangleFlag = true;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

after selecting a rectangle. Then when you press the crop button, you can check the value of the flag, and if it's false (don't forget to initialize it at the beginning), then return and don't do anything.

Eg. in cropButton_Callback

```
if handles.SelectRectangleFlag == false
msgbox('Please select a rectangle before pressing the Crop button');
    return
end
```

Hope that helps! I hope it was clear enough. If not please ask :)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I will try it and let you know whether it worked :)